# Google's End-to-End Example of Google Schema Implementation

Tags: google-schemas

I followed the End-To-End example (https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/actions/end-to-end-example) of setting up a "Submit a Review" schema to a "T", but I'm still not seeing the schema card appear in the inbox preview.

The email is triggering (e.g. http://monosnap.com/image/TxtltNeeeCetTWG22xz4xLGSA), but the card isn't appearing.

Has anyone successfully reproduced the End-to-End example on the site?

Answer (score 2):

As reported in the [Reference guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/review-action), the Review Action is currently not supported in Gmail. It will still take a couple of weeks before that action becomes available to everyone.

You can try replacing that action with another one (e.g. a [One-Click Action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/one-click-action)) to see a button show up in Gmail.